# aChartEngine - How to mask bars?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I have created a bar chart with `aChartEngine`. The problem I have is that bars are created for each value, including 0. This means that where there is a value of 0, it creates a space between the adjacent bars.

I would like to get rid of that space - I think the only way is to either remove or hide bars when their value is 0. I have looked for a solution online and tried different things - like setting the bar spacing to 0 - but so far I have found nothing that works.

Here's my code:

```
//DATA 1
    int[] y = {5, 0, 8, 13, 0, 16, 8};
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Category 1");
    for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
        series.add(y[i]);
    }

    //DATA 2
    int[] y2 = {0, 5, 0, 10, 0, 0, 3};
    CategorySeries series2 = new CategorySeries("Category 2");
    for(int i = 0; i < y2.length; i++){
        series2.add(y2[i]);
    }

    //DATA 3
    int[] y3 = {25, 5, 2, 9, 22, 24, 6};
    CategorySeries series3 = new CategorySeries("Category 3");
    for(int i = 0; i < y3.length; i++){
        series3.add(y3[i]);
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    dataset.addSeries(series2.toXYSeries());
    dataset.addSeries(series3.toXYSeries());

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 10);
    renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer2.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 10);
    renderer2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer3.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 10);
    renderer3.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("MY GRAPH");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Y AXIS TITLE");
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0);

    mRenderer.setXLabels(1);
    mRenderer.setYLabels(12);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "col 1");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "col 2");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "col 3");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "col 4");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "col 5");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, "col 6");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(7, "col 7");
    mRenderer.setFitLegend(true);       

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
```

Would anyone have any idea of how to remove or mask only certain bars?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a value of `0` is still a value and needs to be displayed. If you don't want to display it then maybe just skip it in your code logic.

Another possible solution would be to use `MathHelper.NULL_VALUE` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, I can't skip the null values.I ended up keeping them and made the bar spacing larger so it doesn't look too confusing.

Comment: @ Dan, How can I use MathHelper.NULL_VALUE instead of 0?

Comment: @ Dan, In my case the bars get visible for 0 values also. I need to show bars for values more than 0.